# Call method from this class to another that just call

Tags: call, back

I have classA and classB
in class A I call create classB like this:

classB b = new classB();
b.method();

in class B, I want to call back to class A when method done
How can I do that, please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to call back exactly to class A? A simple solution(and maybe not the best) would be to use a global variable because both class A and class B are in class A. You could also instantiate a class A variable in class B and create a method in class A that sends some variable back to Class A once a method in Class B is done such as:

In classB:

```
classB b = new classB();
classA a = new classA();
b.method();
a.sendResultToClassAMethod(some variable);
```

In classA:

```
method sendResultToClassAMethod(some variable){
       this.variable = variable;
      }
```

I hope this helps